# Retrieve nested Json when some of the keys are random

Tags: java, json, loops, parsing, nested

So in Java, I have this as my json String:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringJson = "{\n" +
            "nodes: {\n" +
            "Random-key-Here: {\n" +
            "name: \"PRO-cnt-elastic2-4-i-0a414518a5b67\",\n" +
            "transport_address: \"172.18.7.104:9300\",\n" +
            "host: \"189.88.7.884\",\n" +
            "ip: \"188.88.8.884:8880\",\n" +
            "roles: [\n" +
            "\"ingest\"\n" +
            "],\n" +
            "attributes: {\n" +
            "zone: \"us-east-1a\"\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "tasks: {\n" +
            "Random-key-Here: {\n" +
            "node: \"-2688888mRPYHywWA\",\n" +
            "id: 37202060,\n" +
            "type: \"transport\",\n" +
            "action: \"indices:data/write/reindex\",\n" +
            "status: {\n" +
            "total: 4869544,\n" +
            "updated: 13920,\n" +
            "created: 3654080,\n" +
            "deleted: 0\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "description: \"blaaa\",\n" +
            "start_time_in_millis: 1596456902705,\n" +
            "running_time_in_nanos: 647855785005,\n" +
            "cancellable: true,\n" +
            "headers: { }\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "}";

    JsonObject jo = new JsonParser().parse(stringJson).getAsJsonObject();
    Set s = jo.get("nodes").getAsJsonObject().entrySet().stream().map(e ->
            e.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("tasks").collect(toSet());
}
```

**Important**: notice inside the Json some of the Keys are actually a random string that I couldn't know what it is in advance... - so I Wrote them as "Random-key-Here"

In short: My goal is to retrieve the number of this field, "total: 4869544".

Above that's what I've tried. I've managed to have a list that contains one object member of a set, and it's the "Random-key-Here" as the key, and the value is the rest of my nested json.

I thought if I would repeat the same logic as I did to overcome the first "Random-key-Here" thing, like I did with

```
.entrySet().stream().map(e -> 
        e.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("tasks")
```

then I would get to another level below, so instead of "tasks" I wrote "status"
and I tought then I would be able to get the rest of the nested json which is easier from then on... but instead, nothing is returned when doing that:

```
jo.get("nodes").getAsJsonObject().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("tasks").getAsJsonObject().entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(ent-> ent.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("status").getAsJsonObject().get("total").getAsJsonObject()))
```

would appreciate any help to get to the nested part I need which is: "total: 4869544".
and keep in mind, I can't simply just use this:

```
jo.get("nodes").getAsJsonObject().get("Random-key-Here").getAsJsonObject().get("tasks")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("Random-key-Here").getAsJsonObject()
        .get("status").getAsJsonObject().get("total").getAsInt()
```

because of "Random-key-Here".

Tnx for the helpers!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself: So, on every unknown key that you have, you can use `entrySet()`
and then loop over it until you get to your desired field member.
so this usage solves the problem and can get you the nested Json even when your key is unknown in advance:

```
 jo.get("nodes").getAsJsonObject().entrySet()
     .forEach(node -> node.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("tasks").getAsJsonObject().entrySet()
          .forEach(task -> { int i = task.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("status").getAsJsonObject().get("total").getAsInt(); 
                System.out.println(i); }))
```

pls share if someone has a more efficient way to do so